# Error in sending entire variable from raspberrypi (python) to arduino

Tags: arduino, pyserial, serial-communication

I want to transfer a number"500" stored in a variable "int3" from python to arduino via serial communication.
The arduino reads the data using Serial.read(), but prints only "5".
Thanks in advance.
I have int3, byte 2 and byte 3 to be sent from python, but want arduino to print the value of int3.

```py
import serial
import time
ser=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0',9600)
int3 = 500
int3 = b'%d' %int3
while (1):

    ser.write(int3)
    ser.write(b'2')
    ser.write(b'3')
#print type(ser.write)
    time.sleep(1)
    print(int3)
```

```
String r;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
//  while(!Serial)
//  {
//    ;
//  }
}
void loop(){
  if(Serial.available() > 0){  
    r =(Serial.read() - 0);  //conveting the value of chars to integer
Serial.print(r[0]);


delay(100);
//while(Serial.available () !=0) r=Serial.read();
}



}
```

Comment: Because `Serial.read` only returns the first incoming byte. The `delay` blocks the application so the other two bytes are discarded.

Comment: Should I remove the delay?

Comment: What is the solution if I want all three bytes?

Comment: Why not send the `int` in it's binary (and fixed length) form instead of converting twice?

Comment: Make a loop, check if a byte is available, when available add the byte to a buffer, leave the loop when the buffer is full, a stop is received or with some other kind of condition.

Comment: @Kampi, will the Serial.readString() help? Also, what kind of loop were you suggesting? I am new to this

Comment: @danny_ds, I tried it, still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the if with a while loop:

```
String fromRaspberry;
void loop(){
  char c;
  while (Serial.available() > 0) {  
    c = Serial.read(); //read char
    fromRaspberry += c; //add the read char to string
  }
  int x = fromRaspberry.toInt(); //convert string to int
  Serial.println(x);
  // clear the string for new input:
  fromRaspberry = "";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working. However, if I am trying to send three variables for example, int1= 100, int2=250,int3=350. When I used, what you suggested. I get the values of all the variables, but now, I want to print the value of only int1(i.e 100). If i try, Serial.println(r[0],), the arduino serial monitor prints '1' and not '100' as required.

Comment: Add a delimiter character for example a new line character after each sent int from the raspberry, and check for that character. When you receive  a new line, you know you have received a complete int. Check this example on how to find the newline character: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial.StringToIntExample